Characterization of the discrete spectrum
I am following Bernard Helffer's book on spectral theory. We have a Proposition

Let $T$ be a self-adjoint operator. Then $\lambda $ is in the discrete spectrum iff $\lambda$ is an isolated eigenvalue of $T$ with finite eigenspace.

Here the discrete spectrum is defined as
$$  \lambda \in \sigma _d(T) \iff \lambda \in \sigma(T) \text{ and } \mathrm{dim\,} \mathrm{ran\,}  E_{(\lambda - \varepsilon, \lambda+ \varepsilon)} < \infty , 
$$
where $E_{\lambda}$ is the associated spectral family.
The book argues as follows

If $\lambda \in \sigma_{\text {disc }}(T)$, we can immediately see that there exists $\epsilon_0$ such that, $\forall \epsilon \in] 0, \epsilon_0[, E_{] \lambda-\epsilon, \lambda+\epsilon[ }$ becomes a projector independent of $\epsilon$ with finite range. This is actually the projector $\Pi_\lambda=1_{\{\lambda\}}(T)$, and we observe moreover that $E_{] \lambda, \lambda+\epsilon_0[ }=0$ and $E_{] \lambda-\epsilon_0, \lambda[ }=0$. This shows that $\lambda$ is an isolated point in $\sigma(T)$.

I am not quite sure how the uniformity in $\epsilon$ is established and then how can we rigorously establish the form of the projector. Formally, taking a limit in $\epsilon$, it seems reasonable but I am not sure how to argue it formally. Please also illustrate the backward direction as I am not able to follow the books argument.

The requirement that the eigenspace be finite-dimensional is, to me, unhelpfully technical. Sure, (non-zero) eigenspaces of compact, self-adjoint operators (our buddies) are finite-dimensional, but it is very easy to find operators with infinite-dimensional eigenspaces... E.g., the identity operator on an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space. :)

@paulgarrett Please correct me if I am wrong but my thinking was as follows: If $E_{(\lambda - \varepsilon , \lambda+ \varepsilon)}$ was not projecting on a uniform range, then pick a sequence indexed by $ k$ such that $ E_{(\lambda - \varepsilon k , \lambda + \varepsilon k)}$ which projects on a subspace $ V_k$ and $ V_k \neq V{k+ 1}$ by construction. In particular, we can find points $ u_k \neq u{k + 1}$ such that $ E_{(\lambda - \varepsilon _k, \lambda+ \varepsilon _k)} u_k = u_k$.

This implies that $ E_{(\lambda - \varepsilon _0 , \lambda  + \varepsilon 0)} u_k = u_k, \forall  k$ and hence $ E{(\lambda - \varepsilon _0, \lambda+ \varepsilon _0)}$ is infinite dimensional. This contradiction would otherwise would not have been possible.

Ah, well, ok, but this seems to me to be more a matter of convention/definition than of mathematical fact. E.g., we can easily make an (self-adjoint, if you like) operator on a separable Hilbert space that has infinitely-many eigenvalues (discrete spectrum), each with (countably) infinite-dimensional eigenspace. We cannot "prove" that this is impossible. Are you wanting to make a convention that somehow excludes this?

We know that there exists $\varepsilon_1>0$ such that $\dim\operatorname{ran}E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon_1,\lambda+\varepsilon_1)}<\infty$. Now if $0<\varepsilon\leq\varepsilon_1$ we have $E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}\leq E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon_1,\lambda+\varepsilon_1)}$ and so $\dim\operatorname{ran}E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}\leq \dim\operatorname{ran}E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon_1,\lambda+\varepsilon_1)}$. Now since the dimension is finite, it can only decrease a finite number of times as we make $\varepsilon$ smaller, thus there exists $0<\varepsilon_0\leq\varepsilon_1$ such that $\dim\operatorname{ran}E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon_0,\lambda+\varepsilon_0)}$ is minimal among all $0<\varepsilon\leq\varepsilon_1$. Then for any $0<\varepsilon\leq\varepsilon_0$ we have $\dim\operatorname{ran}E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}=\dim\operatorname{ran}E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon_0,\lambda+\varepsilon_0)}$ and $E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}\leq E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon_0,\lambda+\varepsilon_0)}$, so $E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}=E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon_0,\lambda+\varepsilon_0)}$. This takes care of the first sentence. We have $E_{\{\lambda\}}=s-\lim_{\varepsilon\searrow0}E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}$, so $E_{\{\lambda\}}=E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}$ for $0<\varepsilon\leq\varepsilon_0$. And in general $E_{\{\lambda\}}$ is the orthogonal projection onto the $\lambda$ eigenspace. For the last part: $$E_{\{\lambda\}}=E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon_0,\lambda+\varepsilon_0)}=E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon_0,\lambda+\varepsilon_0)\setminus\{\lambda\}}+E_{\{\lambda\}},$$ so $E_{(\lambda-\varepsilon_0,\lambda+\varepsilon_0)\setminus\{\lambda\}}=0$. This implies that $\sigma(T)\cap ((\lambda-\varepsilon_0,\lambda+\varepsilon_0)\setminus\{\lambda\})=\emptyset$ (this is a part of the spectral theorem, the projection corresponding to a non-empty open subset of the spectrum is non-zero).

How do you get $$ E_{{\lambda}}  = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} E_{(\lambda - \varepsilon , \lambda + \varepsilon)}
$$
considering the book only defines
$$  E_{\lambda ^+} := \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} E_{(\lambda , \lambda + \varepsilon )} , \quad E_{\lambda ^{-}} := \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} E_{(\lambda - \varepsilon, \lambda )}
$$

This follows from the strong operator continuity of the Borel functional calculus: $\chi_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}}\to\chi_{{\lambda}}$ pointwise (and they are uniformly bounded, supported in a set of finite measure), so $E_{{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}}=\chi_{(\lambda-\varepsilon,\lambda+\varepsilon)}}(T)\to\chi_{{\lambda}}=E_{{\lambda}}$ strongly
